# Coordinates validation

Tags: vue.js, validation, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I have text field for coordinates and i would like to vlaidate it using vee-validate (3.x) and vue 2. I have tried two different aproches, but neither of them work. The format should be in format "int or float,int or float" "latitude,longitude" (with only one coma, multiple comas should be flagged as invalid)

This is the textfield:

```html
<ValidationProvider v-slot="{ errors }" rules="coordinates_validation">
            <v-text-field
              :label="$t('stations.position')"
              :value="positionValue"
              :error-messages="errors"
              @input="$emit('update:station', { ...station, ...getLatLong($event) })"
              @keypress="justNumber"
            />
</ValidationProvider>
```

These are the two aproches i have tried, but neither of them work:

```js
extend("coordinates_validation", {
  validate: (value) => {
    const coordinates = value.split(",");

    if (coordinates.length !== 2) {
      return false;
    }

    const trimmedCoordinates = coordinates.map((coord) => coord.trim());

    const isValidCoordinate = (coord) => {
      return !Number.isNaN(parseFloat(coord)) && Number.isFinite(coord);
    };

    return (
      trimmedCoordinates.every(isValidCoordinate) &&
      !trimmedCoordinates.some((coord) => coord === "")
    );
  },
  message: i18n.tc("validations.coordinates_incorrect_format"),
});
```

```js
extend('coordinates_validation', {
  validate: (value) => {
    const regex = /^\d+(\.\d+)?,\s*\d+(\.\d+)?$/;
    return regex.test(value);
  },
  message: i18n.tc('validations.coordinates_incorrect_format'),
});
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

*When in doubt, console.log it out*

See my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-forked-tw5psv?file=/src/Demo.vue) where I console.log each step of your validation, splitting big steps into smaller steps where necessary.

For your first attempt, the problem is [Number.isFinite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite) always returning false. This is because you feed it a string `coord` but `Number.isFinite` expects a number.  The fix is then:

```
Number.isFinite(parseFloat(coord))
```

Your initial `value.split` also only works with comma `,`.  I suggest splitting on space  , comma `,` and comma + any amount of space `,`

```js
const coordinates = value.split(/[,\s]\s*/);
```

For your second attempt using just regex, I see nothing wrong. I put the code in the same [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-forked-tw5psv?file=/src/Demo.vue) and when used as the validation method it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, the validation works now, but i have a different problem now, regarding the emit shown, because the emit happens even tho the input is invalid, is there any possible way to make a function, that would ensure the emit only happens if the input is valid?

Comment: Yes, you can tie `@input` to your validation.  Have `@input` call a new method, and you'll probably want to use [ValidationObserver](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/components/validation-observer.html#validate-before-submit) to get the validation state then emit based on the returned state.